# Extract data based on Id column for each distinct 50K Ids

Tags: mysql

I have a table of record count 15 million but distinct ids are 5 million.
I am required to split this data for each of 50 thousand distinct ids and extract it in file.

Below code would be too much hectic and manual to work with.

```
select * from 'TableName' where Id in (1,2,....50K)
```

Can it be done by some function.

Comment: You have 15 million records with 5 million distinct ids that you want to split into 50 thousand distinct ids - I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be much easier to put all the IDs you want to run the Query with into a temporary Table and then join it in your query.

```
select *
from  TableName
join  #IdTable on TabeleName.ID = #IdTable .ID
```